# How can I create multiple views for a table in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a single table in which I store favourite dishes of users. A user can have more than one entries in the table.
I have generated a view to show all the entries in the table but how do I create a view to show just the list of users. I don't have a table saving the users so I have to use DISTINCT to get the names of the users from my one and only table

Comment: you could make a new action on the UsersController called user_list or something

Comment: I did add an action called user_list and created a new view and route for it. but here is what happens   when i go to the link http://localhost:3000/foodsIlike/user_list instead of going to the user_list it tries to find a record with :id=user_list as that is what it would do to show one record

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you have a lot to learn about relational databases, schema design and data modeling so this answer might not help very much but here goes...

You're at a point where you should [normalize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) your schema and put users in their own table. Then the dishes table would have a `user_id` field pointing back to the `id` of the user it `belongs_to`.

So, you'll have a User model that `has_many` Dishes. And a Dish model that `belongs_to` User. With that you'll more easily be able to create views for users without having to do a slightly complex query to get that data out of the Dish table.

Comment: I understand and know what you are saying but am trying a one table application ...ie. no relational database.. is it a bad idea

Comment: I think it is a routing problem .. I am not able to override the /foodsIlike/:id  path by   /foodsIlike/user_list

Comment: Try putting the user list route above the I'd route

Answer (score 0):

My routes had to be fixed and it worked ..

The default route.rb looks like this

> ActionController::Routing::Routes.draw do |map|
>     # The priority is based upon order of creation
>     # First created gets highest
>    priority.
>
> # Sample of regular route:   # map.connect 'products/:id',
>   :controller => 'catalog',
>                                   :action => 'view'   # Keep in mind you can assign values other than   # :controller and :action
>
> # Sample of named route:   # map.purchase 'products/:id/purchase',
>   :controller => 'catalog',
>                                             :action => 'purchase'   # This route can be invoked with purchase_url(:id => product.id)
>
> # You can have the root of your site routed by hooking up ''   # --
>   just remember to delete public/index.html.   # map.connect '',
>   :controller => "welcome"
>
> # Allow downloading Web Service WSDL as a file with an extension
>
> # instead of a file named 'wsdl'   map.connect
>   ':controller/service.wsdl', :action => 'wsdl'
>
> # Install the default route as the lowest priority.   map.connect
>   ':controller/:action/:id.:format'   map.connect
>   ':controller/:action/:id'
>   end

I found this tutorial helpfull
http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1087656&seqNum=5